# Integrating SSH and SCP in python to communicate with multiple servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssh, scp

I have 3 servers

```
Server1 - Local server
Server2 - Intermediary Server
Server3 - Server on which files are present .
```

Due to network configurations Server3 can only be accessed via Server2 .
The steps I follow to fetch files from Server3 to Server1 are -

```
1. ssh into Server2 from Server1.
2. scp files from server3 to server2
3. scp files from server2 to server1.
```

I need help in creating a python script that executes on server1(local machine) and fetches file from server3.
I don't want to copy my python script to server2 as it would defeat the purpose of writing this script .

Comment: Do you really need a Python script? You can configure `scp` to use server2 as the "jump point" for connecting to server3 directly from server1. Something like `scp -J server2 server3:/path/to/file/foo.txt local_foo.txt`.

Comment: @chepner PermitTunneling is disabled in the all the servers and I cannot update the sshd_config file , therefore direct tunnelling is not possible from server1.

Comment: Does `ssh` need `tun` support? I thought that was an *option*, but `-J` just opens another `ssh` connection in the background. AFAIK, it just automates what you are looking to do.

Comment: On executing `scp -J` I am getting the error `channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed`